error importing mapped_column pythonanywhere
I am trying to deploy a flask webapp into pythonanywhere, have configured the WGSI, uploaded the files but when I try to access the webapp comes the message "an error has occured". The error.log file prints:

2024-06-05 14:40:08,729: Error running WSGI application
2024-06-05 14:40:08,729: ImportError: cannot import name 'mapped_column' from 'sqlalchemy.orm' (/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/init.py)
2024-06-05 14:40:08,730:   File "/var/www/viniciusmoura_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 13, in 
2024-06-05 14:40:08,730:     from app import app as application
2024-06-05 14:40:08,730:
2024-06-05 14:40:08,730:   File "/home/viniciusmoura/mysite/app.py", line 9, in 
2024-06-05 14:40:08,730:     from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base, Mapped, mapped_column

the mapped_column is being used to declare tables on SQLite database:

class Clientes(db.Model):
id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, primary_key=True)
nome: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)
pj: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(Integer, nullable=False)
email: Mapped[str] = mapped_column(String(250), nullable=False)

The WGSI file:

import sys
project_home = '/home/viniciusmoura/mysite'
if project_home not in sys.path:
sys.path = [project_home] + sys.path
#import flask app but need to call it "application" for WSGI to work
from app import app as application  # noqa

I have found on stackoverflow to change mapped_column to Column but it leads to other erros. Also, I added a requirements.txt file and installed it with bash console. the requirements.file:

Flask
Werkzeug
flask_bootstrap
flask_login
flask_sqlalchemy
SQLAlchemy
pandas

What are the alternatives?

mapped_column was added in SQLAlchemy 2.0. Try running pip install --upgrade sqlalchemy in the bash console to update it.
